# How to modify _loginPartial.cshtml to display custom user data instead of UserName?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET Core MVC, where I have scaffolded Identity. Now, I created an ApplicationUser class that derives from IdentityUser class, where I have added my properties, as shown below:

```
    namespace MonitoringFinances.Models 
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, in the generated _loginPartial.cshtml view shown below, I would like to show Hello @FirstName! instead of Hello @userName!.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Can someone please help this newbie in .NET Core? I'd greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: Which options you have tried so far?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij I tried to inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, but that was giving me a hard time with Startup.cs file. I thought about getting the User from the UserManager and then getting the FirstName, although that was also giving me troubles.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

Here's my solution to this:

```
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = (ApplicationUser) await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var firstName = applicationUser.FirstName;
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @firstName!</a>
```

I am not sure if this goes against MVC principles since I am doing some slight code in a view, but it does work. Let me know if a better solution is available.